# Drop Down list is not working to change between values

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

I've created this dropdown menu to switch between charts based on URL of that chart, **but it is not working on either in VS code or on my site !**

basically, I want to change the chart when I select the other country from dropdown menu

Here is my code:

```js
function switchVis(chartId) {
  document.querySelector('iframe').src = 'https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/' + chartId;
}
```

```html
<p>Select country</p>

<select onchange="switchVis(this.value)">
  <option value="SRbHj/4/">Belguim</option>
  <option value="BGQvN/4/">Austria</option>
</select>


<iframe src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/SRbHj/4/" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width: 0; min-width: 100% !important; border: none;" height="407"></iframe>
```

Comment: Looks like it's working here...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I am confused about that ! . I am trying it on my site but it is not working there !

Comment: First... your code works.. at least the snippet did. This is a guess and I have not tested it here... but It might be because of your local/site are using http and the `iframe` is using https.